# Spark Java Version Errors

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.1.1 Scala 2.11.8 and Java 8

Main Java Spark class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class SparkSample {

     private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App");

        //Duration the interval at which streaming data will be divided into batches
        JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new     JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("MY-TOPIC".split(",")));
        Map<String, String> kafkaConfiguration = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaConfiguration.put("metadata.broker.list", "MYIP:9092");
        kafkaConfiguration.put("group.id", "Stream");

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            javaStreamingContext,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaConfiguration,
            topicsSet
    );
        messages.print();
        //BELOW PART THROWS ERRORS IF UNCOMMENTED
        //JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
        //JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x ->     Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
        //JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
        //    .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
        //wordCounts.print();

        // Start the computation
        javaStreamingContext.start();
        javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
    }

}
```

Dependencies:

```xml
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId> <!-- spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-->
    <version>1.6.3</version> <!-- 1.6.3 2.0.1-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The code that is commented throws the following error when uncommented:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

If I keep it commented then it prints messages just fine. Any ideas why? I am building/compiling with Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error suggests that you're running Java code compiled for a version too new for the runtime version on which you run it. It's likely that Java 7 or earlier is the default on your machine (driver, worker, master, etc.)

Things you need to check and/or fix:

- Check that the runtime matches your target. Use `java -version` on the command line where you run your spark application. **This must be done both on the driver machine and on each machine in your cluster**. All of them must have the correct version of Java for your code.
- You may need to change your target compile version if you're compiling for an earlier Java version (if you want to run on earlier versions):

  ```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
  ```
- Ensure that your spark user's `JAVA_HOME` resolves to the correct Java installation directory. Also check that the `PATH` environment variable includes the correct `$JAVA_HOME/bin` path.

Comment: My spark master and workers all use Java 8. I think the problem is the libraries I am using. I think one of the libraries is compiled with Java 7. I will try compiling the whole project with Java 7 instead.